# Will there be a problem if I use a single server for multiple messenger bot?

Tags: facebook-messenger-bot, facebook-webhooks

I have two messenger bot

- Bot-01
- Bot-02

In my server, I created two webHook like

- myDomain/webhook/bot01_Id
- myDomain/webhook/bot02_Id

While I verify webHook, I find each specific bot Information from the database and verifying it.

While sending a message, I am doing the same.

It works fine in development, I am using ngRok.

My query is, will it be a problem in production that I am running multiple bots using the same server?

Is there any restriction that I can not run multiple bots using a single server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No there is no restriction on multiple bots on same server. I have 4 bots running on same server on production. Just keep in check if your server is capable enough to handle all the users from both bot.

Comment: Should I use individual facebook app for each bot or should I use a single app for 2 bots?

Comment: If you use same app for multiple bots, you will have 1 webhook. When any response comes from any bot, you can identify it from the page id. 
If you use different app for different bots, you will have different webhook for each. 
Both options are totally possible. It's your choice what you want to do.
I use different apps for different bots.

Comment: If I use individual apps for each of the bots, then I have to go through the review process for each bot, right?

Comment: Yes you have to go review process for pages_messaging permission. But if you have business verification process already done, you don't have to go through it again.